# package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’

Tags: r, r-mice

I am trying to install `mice` package in RStudio and am getting the following error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘mice’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
     there is no package called ‘lme4’
```

I also tried to install `lme4` using the following command.

```
install.packages("lme4")
```

But I got the following error:

```
also installing the dependency ‘RcppEigen’
...
17 warnings generated.
clang++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -std=gnu++14 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o RcppEigen.so RcppEigen.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRlapack -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -lRblas -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0 -L/usr/local/gfortran/lib -lgfortran -lquadmath -lm -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [RcppEigen.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘RcppEigen’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/RcppEigen’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘RcppEigen’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘RcppEigen’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/lme4’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

Here are the results of `sessionInfo()`:

```
R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6

Matrix products: default
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] naniar_1.0.0   readr_2.1.4    psych_2.3.9    pastecs_1.3.21 ggplot2_3.4.3 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] shape_1.4.6       tidyselect_1.2.0  xfun_0.40         purrr_1.0.2       splines_4.2.3     lattice_0.20-45  
 [7] colorspace_2.1-0  vctrs_0.6.3       generics_0.1.3    htmltools_0.5.6   yaml_2.3.7        utf8_1.2.3       
[13] survival_3.5-3    rlang_1.1.1       pillar_1.9.0      glue_1.6.2        withr_2.5.0       foreach_1.5.2    
[19] lifecycle_1.0.3   munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.4      evaluate_0.21     codetools_0.2-19  knitr_1.43       
[25] tzdb_0.4.0        fastmap_1.1.1     parallel_4.2.3    fansi_1.0.4       broom_1.0.5       Rcpp_1.0.11      
[31] scales_1.2.1      backports_1.4.1   mnormt_2.1.1      hms_1.1.3         digest_0.6.33     visdat_0.6.0     
[37] dplyr_1.1.3       grid_4.2.3        cli_3.6.1         tools_4.2.3       magrittr_2.0.3    glmnet_4.1-8     
[43] tibble_3.2.1      tidyr_1.3.0       pkgconfig_2.0.3   Matrix_1.5-3      rmarkdown_2.24    rstudioapi_0.15.0
[49] iterators_1.0.14  R6_2.5.1          boot_1.3-28.1     nlme_3.1-162      compiler_4.2.3
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what code you used when trying to install, what error messages you received when trying to install `lme4`, and the results of `sessionInfo()` please/

Comment: @user20650
I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I don't use a mac so can't help but the error message points to requiring fortran. Regarding this, I have seem ointers to https://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/cpp/r-compiler-tools-for-rcpp-on-macos/ or to just installing the binary package.